# How to override MUI PaperProps with styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI and I want to override the width of the menu with styled components.

I tried this:

```
const StyledMenu = styled(Menu)`
  && {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

And nothing happened.

Then I found out that MUI has the PaperProps and when applying:

```
<StyledMenu
  id="menu-appbar"
  PaperProps={{
    style: {
      width: '100%',
    },
  }}
>
```

I got the desiered result but I would like to accomplish it via styled-components, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every style that you write in `PaperProps` attribute will make it's impact in `.MuiPaper-root` class.
So your code can be like this:

```
const StyledMenu = styled(Menu)`
  && {
    & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
`;
```

More insights can be found in the [docs](https://v4.mui.com/guides/interoperability/#deeper-elements-2).